# How to only mock a method of a bean in Spring using Mockito?

Tags: spring, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I use `@Primary` and `@Profile` to mock a bean in Spring test:

```
@Profile("test")
@Configuration
public class TestBeanConf {

@Bean
@Primary
public UserService userService() {
    UserService userService = Mockito.mock(UserService.class);
    TokenValidationUrl validation = new TokenValidationUrl();
    validation.setValid(true);
    validation.setUid("123456789");
    Mockito.when(userService.tokenValidation("23456")).thenReturn(validation);
    return userService;
}
```

But other methods of `UserService` bean return `null`, how can i spy the real created bean and only mock `tokenValidation` method?

Answer (score 4):

To spy one method of `UserService` bean, during construction of this bean we autowire existing instance of UserService from Spring context by sending it as paramter and use Mockito’s spying feature:

```
@Profile("test")
@Configuration
public class TestBeanConf {

@Bean
@Primary
public UserService userServiceTest(UserService userService) {
    UserService userService = Mockito.spy(userService);
    TokenValidationUrl validation = new TokenValidationUrl();
    validation.setValid(true);
    validation.setUid("123456789");
    Mockito.when(userService.tokenValidation("23456")).thenReturn(validation);
    return userService;
}
```