# spock, mock a method response in a spring bean

Tags: spring, spock

I have an integration test written in groovy (spock) in spring boot application. One of the application beans is called `Validator` it has the follwoing method:

```
public void validateIssueDates(final List<Timestamp> issueDates) {
    issueDates.forEach(issueDate -> {
        final Timestamp now = Timestamp.valueOf(LocalDateTime.now());

        if (issueDate.before(now)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Issue date is before current date");
        }
    });
}
```

In the `Validator` class there are other methods. In my `spock` integration test I would like to mock response for that particular method only. In the following way:

```
Validator.validateIssueDates(_) >> null
```

I want other validations to take place, but not this one. Bascially I want to achieve [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45649545/how-to-only-mock-a-method-of-a-bean-in-spring-using-mockito) but with spock. I would like to eliminate the `validateIssueDates()` method from being executed

Comment: You should put your solutions in an answer see https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: good point. Done. Thanks for the remark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### solution using `Spock`

It's done using [@SpringSpy][2].
First we annotate field with a spring bean we want to wrap in spy object. For example:

```
@SpringSpy
private CarValidator carValidator;
```

then in our test, in `then` part we define how we want to override method from a a bean/spy:

```
then:
    3 * carValidator.validateIssueDates(_) >> null
```

---

### Solution using `Mockito` (as an additional approach, it's not related to spock solution)

I have got that pretty easy using `spy` in `Mockito`. Despite many trials (and errors) with `spock`'s `spy`, It just doesn't want to work. If I get that, I post it here. For now, I can only share `Mockito` solution:

```
@Profile("test")
@Configuration
public class BeanConfig {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public CarValidator getCarValidatorSpy(CarValidator validator) {
        CarValidator carValidatorSpy = Mockito.spy(validator);

        Mockito.doNothing().when(carValidatorSpy).validateIssueDates(Mockito.any(CarDto.class));
        return carValidatorSpy;
    }
}
```

---

That's all. Seems fairly straightforward.